# How can we update the tile in Windows Phone 7 like the in build people app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to make a Windows Phone App. I could not find any resources about updating the tiles like it is done in people app. Is the people app having special features because the it is in-build?

If not they should be joining all the profile pics and showing as a new tile image every time a an update happens. If this is what happening, how is it been done, from the coding perceptive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the People tile, then no, you can't create a animated tile like that.

But generally you can create very custom tiles, and you can utilize the flip-functionality, and display two different tiles. If you run it as a background service, you can also update the image(s) every 30th minute.

I [wrote a guide](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-live-tile-directly-o) on how to create advanced tiles.

Comment: oops, yeah I am talking about the people tile.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible as a regular developer. So you're out of luck.

Comment: but making an update every 30 min is too much. this feature cannot be used well.

Comment: What do you mean by regular developer.

Comment: If you worked at a manufacturer (like HTC , Samsung or Nokia), you would have access to more stuff :p